# Partial Fraction Expansion and Laplace Transform

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I have some problem with my equation:
$$y''+5y = 5e^{-5t} $$

And we got that y(0) = 1 and y'(0) = 2

It's too much to write but what I get is:
$$ \frac{e^{-5t}}{6}+1.516676089\cdot \cos(0.989 - \sqrt{5}t)$$
This works with first value y(0)=1 but doesn't work with y'(0).

Btw, where are supposed to use the complex roots and not the easy way with PFE, already solved this if used regular PFE.

Comment: That's what I got when I used the normal PFE way, but got the one above when using complex roots from (s^2 +5)

Comment: What @Moo has written above is correct. It should be simple to invert what he has written there. I don't see what exactly you mean by complex roots being harder.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the Laplace transform, it's quite clear that the fundamental set of solutions to

$$y'' + 5y = 0$$

is

$$y_c = a_1 \sin \sqrt{5} t + a_2 \cos \sqrt{5} t$$

You can get the particular solution by just guessing

$$y_p = ae^{-5t}$$

Thus

$$y = a_1 \sin \sqrt{5} t + a_2 \cos \sqrt{5} t + a e^{-5t}$$

where you will find the coefficients by using the initial conditions, $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0) = 2$.

Comment: Yea, that I knew too, but we're in the part to learn Laplace, so the teacher gave us some different equations.

Comment: Oh I see sorry about that. I'll do it with the Laplace transform

Comment: Haha thanks! The thing is that I did the regular PFE and got this system of equations:

A + B = 1 [s^2], 

5B + c = 7 [s], 

5A + 5C = 15 [1], but this is the wrong way. We're supposed to use this method: A = [(s+5)*Y(s)] where s = -5 etc...

Comment: What do you mean by PFE?

Comment: Partial Fractional Expansion/Decompostion

Comment: If you're just asking about how to do partial fractions you should make the question about this

Comment: I'll come back and finish this later but you should be looking for $$y = \mathcal{L}_s^{-1} \left[ \frac{s^2+7s+15}{(s+5)(s+\sqrt{5}i)(s-\sqrt{5}i)}\right](t)$$